# How to find the files that changed more than X times in a git repo?

Tags: git

I am failing to get this info elsewhere. Is it possible to, for all the files in a repository,find the files that have changed more than X times since the creation of the repository?

Cheers!

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `git log --pretty=format: --name-only | sort | uniq -c | sort -r | awk 'int($1)>here_put_your_number` Let me know if it helped you.